Git commands not working from Visual Studio Code
I am not able to clone a Github repo from Visual Studio Code. I get the error below:
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
fatal: expected flush after ref listing
Everything was working fine until I reinstalled VSC and Node.js (all software) after a machine reset.
Also, the cloning works if I run the command from a terminal window (outside of VSC) so it is not an auth or a repo issue.
I have tried many many suggestions from multiple relevant forums but to no avail. I do not have a thorough understanding of github commands so cannot explain much more about what I did.
The VSC version details if it helps. And I have Node.js 20.x installed.

Everything was working seamlessly earlier (cloning, committing, and syncing) so I expected it would continue to work after the reinstall.

Did you check clone by CMD or Terminal of OS?

there was an recent change in git's credential helper protocol and HTTP layer that messed up vscode integration
dont worry, they'll patch it soon
temporary fix: downgrading to git v2.45.0

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for the update. At least I now know I am not doing anything wrong. Will manage with the cli for now.
